# startActivityForResult starts a second activity which exits the app

Tags: android, android-activity, activity-lifecycle

### Scenario

Activity A (login) starts activity B then finish();

Activity B calls startActivityForResult(Activity C)

Activity C runs nicely, then exits after choosing a phone number (as it should)

-- Back to the desktop (app stops)!

Why didn't it get back to Activity B's onActivityResult()?

### Notes

I have created the proper onActivityResult() on activity B.

I have searched and read every shred of data on stackoverflow about startActivityForResult.

### Code Slips

The code which starts Activity B:

```
ComponentName   component   = new ComponentName("com.emobiletelecom", PokeTALK.class.getName());
    Intent          intent      = new Intent();
    intent.setComponent(component);
startActivity(intent);
    finish();
```

The code which starts Activity C:

```
startActivityForResult(new Intent(this, ContactsPickerActivity.class), 2007);
```

The code finishing Activity C:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.putExtra(KEY_PHONE_NUMBER, contactNumber); 

    setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
    finish();
enter code here
```

### LOG

```
04-23 16:32:27.382: I/ActivityManager(28158): START 

{cmp=com.emobiletelecom/com.codinguser.android.contactpicker.ContactsPickerActivity} from pid 30108
04-23 16:32:27.392: W/WindowManager(28158): Failure taking screenshot for (180x300) to layer 21010
04-23 16:32:27.432: V/PokeTALK(30108): onPause
04-23 16:32:27.642: I/WindowManager(28158): createSurface Window{415eefe8 com.emobiletelecom/com.codinguser.android.contactpicker.ContactsPickerActivity paused=false}: DRAW NOW PENDING
04-23 16:32:27.812: V/PhoneStatusBar(28212): setLightsOn(true)
04-23 16:32:28.042: I/ActivityManager(28158): Displayed com.emobiletelecom/com.codinguser.android.contactpicker.ContactsPickerActivity: +599ms
04-23 16:32:28.192: V/PT(30108): onStop - PokeTALK
04-23 16:33:00.292: D/dalvikvm(28212): GC_CONCURRENT freed 396K, 36% free 10580K/16391K, paused 14ms+8ms
04-23 16:33:24.102: D/dalvikvm(30108): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 189K, 6% free 12032K/12679K, paused 52ms
04-23 16:33:24.122: I/dalvikvm-heap(30108): Grow heap (frag case) to 13.159MB for 1390096-byte allocation
04-23 16:33:24.232: D/dalvikvm(30108): GC_CONCURRENT freed 33K, 6% free 13355K/14087K, paused 4ms+4ms
04-23 16:33:24.341: D/dalvikvm(30108): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 0K, 6% free 13356K/14087K, paused 34ms
04-23 16:33:24.351: I/dalvikvm-heap(30108): Grow heap (frag case) to 14.452MB for 1390096-byte allocation
04-23 16:33:24.522: D/dalvikvm(30108): GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 6% free 14713K/15495K, paused 18ms+5ms
04-23 16:33:27.342: W/WindowManager(28158): Failure taking screenshot for (180x300) to layer 21015
04-23 16:33:27.392: W/NetworkManagementSocketTagger(28158): setKernelCountSet(10005, 1) failed with errno -2
04-23 16:33:27.442: I/WindowManager(28158): createSurface Window{41614cd0 com.android.launcher/com.android.launcher2.Launcher paused=false}: DRAW NOW PENDING
04-23 16:33:27.532: W/InputManagerService(28158): Starting input on non-focused client com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@413fbdb0 (uid=10040 pid=30108)
04-23 16:33:28.292: W/NetworkManagementSocketTagger(28158): setKernelCountSet(10040, 0) failed with errno -2
```

Comment: can you paste your logcat error log

Comment: Adding a the code of how you sent the result to Activity B, and how you handled it, would be better!

Comment: And do you use any Intent flags to start Activity B?

Comment: What flags (if any) do you use to launch the activities? Does activity B runs for some time (waiting for user input?) or it immediately starts activity C?

Comment: can you post the relevant bits of code you use to launch activities?

Comment: Thanks for your swift responses.

I am editing the post with the data you asked for

Comment: As you can see, I use no Intent flags to start any activity

Comment: Do you want your activity stack to be `Home -> A -> B -> C -> B -> Home`?

Comment: I want it really simple: Login -> Main -> Contact Picker -> Main

Comment: Ok, do you ever explicitly call `finish()` in activity B?

Comment: Activity B runs for some time before running activity C.  Activity C is actually a contact picker which gets called when someone clicks on a button on the activity B layout button

Comment: I call finish() on the following methods: onStop(), onKeyDown(back key clicked), finishFromChild(),

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
I call finish() on the following methods: onStop(), onKeyDown(back key clicked), finishFromChild()
```

I believe `finishFromChild()` is where activity B is being accidentally closed. `finishFromChild()` is called when the child activity (C in this hypothetical) calls `finish()`. So this command might be the one closing activity B when you don't mean to.

Comment: Thanks Sam.

You were really close.

It seems that startActivityForResult() calls onPause & onStop, and I had finish() in the onStop() method...

Comment: That would do it too. To clarify my description, B.finishFromChild() is called when C.finish() executes.  So make sure that you are not accidentally calling B.finish() inside B.finishFromChild(), since that will close B as well.

Answer (score 0):

You should not be calling finish() inside activity B when you are launching activity C. Activity B must stick around to receive the result from activity C.

Comment: he never mention that he calling finish in activity b

Comment: The phrase "Activity A (login) starts activity B then finish();" is explained (a little) in "The code which starts Activity B:" section.

Comment: Thanks all - Yeah, I don't finish activity B, it should just return to the form to listen for any button click